# Is it okay to replace urls in already minified files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

I'm trying replace some rev'd urls in my distribution bundles.  We're using isomorphic React.js and there are a few bundle.js paths that need to be the same on client and server, so I need to update these refs in the rev'd bundle.  I'd like to only update the minified bundle, because if I update the bundle with the urls and then minify, my rev hash will be different.  So I'd like to only update the rev'd and minified bundle.

Is it okay to do this?  Will my uglifyjs mangle the url paths so much so that replacing the string at this point is moot?

Also, any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: strings are not minified so should be safe to replace them. keep in mind that minified js is just a js - just with ugly variable names ;)

Comment: awesome, thanks for the sanity check.